# « honey-sauced eulogy »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> Nothing is said about it other than the usual honey-sauced eulogy.

Comment peut-on exprimer de manière idiomatique « honey-sauced eulogy » ?

> Rien n’est dit à ce sujet autre que l'éloge habituel de sauce au miel.

semple-t-elle idiomatique en français ?

Comment: I don't know what is really meant by "honey-sauced" but "de sauce au miel" sounds weird, while "mielleux" could be used instead (but mielleux is often associated with hypocrisy)

Comment: @radouxju: Pas mal, le _mielleux_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il semble que le terme anglais soit d'assez récente origine; je ne le trouve pas dans les dictionnaires. Il est très improbable que la translittération existe, donc ne parlons pas de sa qualité d'être ou non idiomatique. Le terme « **éloge à l'eau de rose** » pourrait cependant convenir; on peut accommoder « à l'eau de rose » un peu à toutes les sauces.

Comment: Since the Principia is one of those works everyone talks of but no one reads,
anything said about it other than the usual **honey-sauced eulogy** must stand up
against righteous indignation from all sides.  (Clifford Truesdell (1960))

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the variations!